# Return array for specific country in json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to find a similar issue that I am having and haven't found it.

This is my json:

```
{
        "name": "United States",
        "code": "US",
        "label": "State",
        ...
        "province_codes": {
          "Alabama": "AL",
           "Alaska": "AK",
           "American Samoa": "AS",
           "Arizona": "AZ",
           "Arkansas": "AR",
           ...
        }
}
```

It's taken from this json repo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnBendfeldt/country-province-data/master/countries.json

I'm trying to get the United States only and get the `province_codes` key and put into a new array for my react component. I've tried the below.

```
const states = [];
countryProvinceData.forEach(field => {
            if (field.name === "United States") {
                field.province_codes.map(code => {
                    states.push({
                        value: code, //Abbreviated state
                        label: code + " (" + code + ")" //full name and abbreviation in brackets
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        this.setState({ states });
```

But it's giving me this error: TypeError: field.province_codes.map is not a function

I hope someone can assist or give guidance.

Comment: `map` is a function of Array prototype and `province_codes` does not seem to be an array

Comment: Also, in general, don't use `map` when you're only interested in side-effects. Use `forEach`. It will make your intentions clear.

Comment: I have also tried forEach and it returns the same error. I know it's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: Well, of course `forEach` doesn't work with your current code. My point was *once you have an array* (by iterating over, e.g., `Object.keys`) use `forEach` instead of `map` if you're only interested in side-effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`province_codes` is an object, but map is an Array prototype's function, in order to loop through object's keys you need to use either `for in` or `Object.keys`

```
Object.keys(field.province_codes).forEach(code => {
  states.push({
    value: code, //Abbreviated state
    label: code + " (" + field.province_codes[code] + ")" //full name and abbreviation in brackets
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Was confused why it was returning that error and it was missing `Object.keys`. Been a long day!